# Unable to connect to Kognitio via Pentaho - Cannot create socket for IP Error

Tags: java, jdbc, pentaho, kognitio-wx2, wx2

My laptop is on Java SE 8 Update 121.  I am running on Pentaho V7.0 "data-integration/lib" contains Kognitio.jar (678 KB)

Below is the error message

```
Error connecting to database [sdf] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class com.kognitio.jdbc.Driver)
[Kognitio][JCommunications](900141) Cannot create socket for IP /XX.XX.XX.XX and port 12345: Connection timed out: connect.


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class com.kognitio.jdbc.Driver)
[Kognitio][JCommunications](900141) Cannot create socket for IP /XX.XX.XX.XX and port 12345: Connection timed out: connect.


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2795)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.test(DatabaseDialog.java:110)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.test(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2$3.widgetSelected(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizard.createAndRunDatabaseWizard(CreateDatabaseWizard.java:131)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.createDatabaseWizard(Spoon.java:7741)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1359)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7990)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9290)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:685)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class com.kognitio.jdbc.Driver)
[Kognitio][JCommunications](900141) Cannot create socket for IP /XX.XX.XX.XX and port 12345: Connection timed out: connect.

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:585)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Kognitio][JCommunications](900141) Cannot create socket for IP /XX.XX.XX.XX and port 12345: Connection timed out: connect.
    at com.simba.communications.ConnectingSocket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.client.core.SCConnection.establishTcpIpConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.client.core.SCConnection.updateConnectionSettings(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:567)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2795)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.test(DatabaseDialog.java:110)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.test(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2$3.widgetSelected(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizard.createAndRunDatabaseWizard(CreateDatabaseWizard.java:131)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.createDatabaseWizard(Spoon.java:7741)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1359)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7990)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9290)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:685)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.simba.communications.exceptions.CommunicationException: [Kognitio][JCommunications](900141) Cannot create socket for IP /XX.XX.XX.XX and port 12345: Connection timed out: connect.
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.communications.ConnectingSocket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.client.core.SCConnection.establishTcpIpConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.client.core.SCConnection.updateConnectionSettings(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:567)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2795)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.test(DatabaseDialog.java:110)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.test(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizardPage2$3.widgetSelected(CreateDatabaseWizardPage2.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.wizard.CreateDatabaseWizard.createAndRunDatabaseWizard(CreateDatabaseWizard.java:131)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.createDatabaseWizard(Spoon.java:7741)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1359)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7990)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9290)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:685)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)

Custom URL     :jdbc:kognitio://XX.XX.XX.XX:12345
Custom Driver Class:com.kognitio.jdbc.Driver
```

Can some one please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the JDBC bridge. Restarting the JDBC bridge did the trick.